# Does tagging a Docker image create a copy of the image?

Tags: docker

Does tagging a Docker image create a copy of the image?

It seems to me tagging by itself shouldn't.
But the following command seems to imply so.

Thanks.

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
friendlyhello            latest              d9e555c53008        3 minutes ago       195MB
python                   2.7-slim            1c7128a655f6        5 days ago          183MB

$ docker tag friendlyhello gordon/get-started:part2

$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
friendlyhello            latest              d9e555c53008        3 minutes ago       195MB
gordon/get-started         part2               d9e555c53008        3 minutes ago       195MB
python                   2.7-slim            1c7128a655f6        5 days ago          183MB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a copy is not made.

You can tell this because the Image ID value is identical:

```
friendlyhello            latest              d9e555c53008        3 minutes ago       195MB
gordon/get-started       part2               d9e555c53008        3 minutes ago       195MB
```

This means they reference the same data.  If you then do a `docker rmi friendlyhello` then it won't delete anything, just remove the tag.

Comment: You're saying that removing the original image will remove the tagged imaged and the original image will remain here?

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad really docker works by the ID number.  When you do an `rmi` what you're really doing is removing a tag.  When there are no tags left (and the image isn't in use) then the image is remove.  So there's always just one image, just with multiple tags.

Comment: seems wired but okay.